# k-th auction confusion from Vitalik's article

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, gas-price, auctions

I was reading an article from Vitalik where he mentions the weaknesses for k-th auction.

If the gasPrices of users are as follows: "0.02, 0.03, 0.05, 0.08, 0.13, 0.19, 1.00" and miner has place for 5 transactions, then he would choose the most-right 5 transactions and make everyone pay 0.05, increasing his revenue.

Vitalik mentions the following problem.

> First, a block proposer can include their own transactions in a block,
> and thereby increase the clearing price, increasing their own total
> revenue.

If miner has space for 5 transactions and we assume that all 5 transactions must be included, then, sure, miner will include two of his own dummy transactions priced at 0.13, causing users with(0.13, 0.19, 1.00) to pay 0.13 as well, i.e miner gained 0.13 * 3. While this is true, I don't understand why miner even needs to submit his own dummy transactions to increase the price ? he can just only include 3 most-right transactions in the block, gaining the same revenue. Why does vitalik even mention dummy transactions by miner at all ? If there was a validation upon consensus that blocks "mostly small" are rejected, then would at least understand it.